# Ruby/Rails: where is the code to generate scaffolds

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, generator, scaffold

I was browsing the code at github.com/rails/rails, and I couldn't figure out where the code was to generate Rails scaffolds. Can anybody shed some light on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb

Did you find that? If you track down it's require, [resource_generator](http://rails/generators/rails/resource/resource_generator), you'll find the code that creates the route. If you track down the resource_generator's requires, you'll find the model generator, helper generator, etc.

You won't find any single file that generates everything.

If I totally misunderstood your question and you just want to know what the command is, it's:

```
cd your/application/directory
```

Rails version < 3.0.0

```
script/generate scaffold model_name column_name:column_type
```

Rails version > 3.0.0

```
rails g scaffold model_name column_name:column_type
```

Comment: You did not misunderstand the qvestion. Thanks for the first part of your answer.